# Auto Generate an Imagemap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can I generate an image-to-map dynamic?

I have an uploaded image like the one below and I want to generate color to map and have functions on it, such as links.

I searched on this but couldn't find how to go about it.

1. [Image Mapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/)
2. [RWD image map](https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps)
3. [qtip](http://qtip1.com/demos/position/imagemap)

Have you any idea for this ?

[image: nothing]

Comment: do you mean a [image map](http://www.image-maps.com/) ?

Comment: i checked it before you say i always create that and iput codes ! but  i am on create admin for that he upload and set links and generate

Comment: I don't really understand you (i.e., "Unclear what you're asking"), but I *think* it's a basic "how do I do this?" question with no attempt shown (i.e., "Too broad").